# Scala Play Guice - override a generic class instance

Tags: scala, playframework, cassandra, guice, quill

I'm trying to override a generic class instance, which doesn't seem to work. Any idea what the syntax for this is?

```
lazy val app: Application = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
        .overrides(bind[CassandraAsyncContext[LowerCase]].toInstance(testCassandraContext))
        .build()
```

It simply doesn't override the orginal instance that comes from Module.scala which looks like this:

```
  @Provides @Singleton
  def provideCassandraContext: CassandraAsyncContext[LowerCase] = {
    new CassandraAsyncContext[LowerCase]("db")
  }
```

Comment: What error message you are getting? this would help to understand problem

Comment: It  just doesn't override the original object instance that comes from the Module.scala

Comment: Related? https://github.com/google/guice/issues/1029

Comment: I have some other dependencies whose classes aren't typed but are still annotated with @Provided and they're all being overridden fine.